# Dart == operator and identical function does not yield true for 2 objects with same content

Tags: oop, dart

So I have been trying to compare two objects by their fields.

I have noticed there is no `equals` method in dart. But there are the `identical` function and the `==` operator.

I can't seem to understand why there is no equals method. What if I want to do this?

```dart
class Name {
  String fname;
  String lname;

  String get firstName => this.fname;
  void set firstName(String fname) => this.fname = fname;

  String get lastName => this.lname;
  void set lastName(String lname) => this.lname = lname;

  Name({this.fname, this.lname});

  @override
  String toString() {
    return this.firstName + " " + this.lastName;
  }

  bool equals(Name n2) {
    return this.firstName == n2.firstName && this.lastName == n2.lastName
        ? true
        : false;
  }
}

void main(List<String> args) {
  Name n1 = new Name();
  n1.firstName = "James";
  n1.lastName = "Bond";

  Name n2 = new Name();
  n2.firstName = "James";
  n2.lastName = "Bond";

  print(n1.equals(n2)); // true
  print(identical(n1, n2)); // false
  print(n1 == n2); // false
}
```

What can I do instead of making my own equals. Or does dart expect you to do this manually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`identical` will not return true even if the first name and last name of the two objects you are comparing are the same. That's because they are not the same instances. Each instance has its own identity and own hashcode.

You could override the == operator and the hashcode. Then you will be able to compare two different instances. The Equatable-Package already does that for you so you can use the == operator two compare two different instances: https://pub.dev/packages/equatable

Comment: Thanks. The overriding was what I was after. I know in java we got an equals method but wasn't sure if you can override the operators themselves in dart.

Comment: Yeah, you can do that in Dart, this article might help you out then: https://medium.com/@dumazy/enhance-your-classes-with-operator-overloading-in-dart-f1124bd813a0

Answer (score 0):

You can write code just like this

```
 @override
  bool operator ==(Object other) {
    if (other.runtimeType != runtimeType)
      return false;
   /// do smth
  }

  @override
  int get hashCode {

  }
```